# email myself startup screen messages log

Tags: linux, email, boot, login, logging

I currently have a NAS (Ubuntu 10.04) on my network without an access to a monitor due to a lack of a graphics card.  I noticed that every time I restart the NAS, it's been taking longer to fully restart.  I suspect that something might be wrong, and the warning or error messages are being displayed during startup.

Is there a log file that Ubuntu prints to for everything that is displayed from the moment the system starts up until the login screen?  I have email set up on the system via `.mailrc` and `.mstmprc` where I could email out with the `mail` command.  I would like to email myself the log file every time the system starts up so I can monitor the system's health.  Please let me know how I could do this.

Comment: try /var/log/messages or /var/log/dmesg

Answer (score 0):

There is such a log file, `/var/log/messages`, to which the kernel dumps whatever happens on the system.

However, it does get rather large (mine is now 29 megabytes), so make sure that your cron job compresses this file before you ship it out.

---

In general on a Linux system, custom startup commands are placed into the `local` file, which can be found under /etc/init.d.

Add to this file the following command (I will probably revise - I don't use `mail`, personally):

`mail -s "Log File" myemail@myserver < /var/log/messages`

Make it executable:

`sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/local`

And finally, link it into `init`:

`sudo update-rc.d local defaults 80`

Reference: [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RcLocalHowto)

Comment: Is this file what is printed on the console screen when the system starts up?  I took a look, and it doesn't seem so.  Showing messages like firewall related stuff (pgl).

How do I set up an email script for every startup?  Thanks.

Comment: @Vinh I belive that the kernel has a debug level system, where only the highest priority messages are shown at boot; this, by contrast, shows everything. As far as emailing yourself, [look into writing an init script and installing it.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto#Installing_custom_init-scripts). I'll extract a summary and put it into my answer.